# AngularJS Dynamic Asset Tags similar to Mixture.io - HTML Templating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-template

Wondering if it's possible to create dynamic asset tags in Angular and, if so, how.

Here's the background: I've been using [Mixture.io](http://docs.mixture.io/templates) for templating and have grown accustomed to the ease and flexibility it offers. I'm now working on my first Angular project and wondering if it's possible to recreate the functionality of Mixture's "magic asset tag" in Angular. Here's what it looks like in Mixture:

```
//Example returning a full script tag:
{{ "index.js" | asset_url | script_tag }}


//Example returning a full stylesheet tag:    
{{ "styles/index.css" | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}


//Example using a standard stylesheet tag:    
<link href="{{ "index.css" | asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


//Example using a standard image tag:    
<img src="{{ "example.jpg" | asset_url }}">
```

*note: the `{{ }}` tags here are [`liquid`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics) syntax used by Mixture, not Angular syntax.*

**Is this possible? If so, ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

Look into [custom filter functions](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09). They allow you to take the input (to the left of the pipe in brackets in your examples) and return a modified version of it. The syntax would even be pretty close to what you're used to working with.